# Add dependencies in Gradle file not auto import in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

I use project structure add the gson library to the build.gradle(Module:app) file, but my Android studio 1.5.1 not auto import the library in the MainActivity.java file. I don't know why...

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that when I use the library by adding the code in MainActivity.java

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

It auto import the library~~~cheers

Answer (score 0):

If it is a library--> 
File>Open Module Setting>Libraries>New Project Library("+" sign in the middle tab)>From Maven> type your Library Name and Apply it